# Entangled coffee plant

Tags: shrubs, repotting, coffee-grounds

6 months ago, I received my first coffee plant that I immediately repotted in a 14" pot. It was 6 " in height, now 2 ft tall. I have recently realized that it was actually made up of 6 plants:

- 2 have not grown (at all)
- 2 have reached 1 ft
- 2 have a much larger trunk. However:

  - one took a turn after reaching 1 ft and is now horizontal
  - the main one has a few bends and turns/grows at an angle.

I would like them to eventually make coffee beans. Should I attempt to separate them now and repot them separately (with some guaranteed damage to the roots) or let them live their life?